# Casting Objects that inherit

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance

Lets say I have 3 very simple objects, `Automobile`, `Car`, `Coach` (to keep it simple).

Automobile has properties:

```
Id / EngineSize / WheelCount / TopSpeed
```

Car inherits from Automobile and has additional properties

```
NumberOfDoors / NumberOfSeats
```

Coach inherits from Automobile and has additional properties

```
NumberOfPassengers / MaxLuggageWeight
```

Now lets say I get my object via an `Id`, and I create a basic helper method, like so to get my object

```
HelperMethod.GetTransport(pId AS Integer) AS OBJECT
```

Now this method will return either a Car or a Coach object.

If i want to set a property on this object, which is within the Automobile class, do i just cast the object that is returned as an Automobile object, like so

```
Dim lMyObject AS Automobile = HelperMethod.GetTransport(1)
lMyObject.EngineSize = 1000
```

Or should i have created an IAutomobile interface, which the base Automobile class would implement and cast the returning object as that, like so:

```
Dim lMyObject AS IAutomobile = HelperMethod.GetTransport(1)
lMyObject.EngineSize = 1000
```

If there a best practice way of doing this?  Are both of these correct and its just up to the programmer?  For some reason i think that the interface one sounds right, but i am not 100% sure.

To expand why this a little.  The reason this is being done is because i have a web application where users can configure these object properties.  Some web pages are used for both objects, because the pages only contain fields that are in the "base" class Automobile.  On these pages, i just want to know how i should be casting the object in order to set the properties in the base class.  I should either do

```
Dim lTransport AS Automobile = HelperMethod.getTransport(1)
lTransport.EngineSize = 1000
```

OR

```
Dim lTransport AS IAutomobile = HelperMethod.getTransport(1)
lTransport.EngineSize = 1000
```

Comment: IMO code would be better than a passage saying inheriance, characteristics and behavior. People here are very good in reading code than a paragraph..

Comment: If `EngineSize` is a member of `AutoMobile` then you shouldn't need the cast (assuming `GetAutomobile` returns `Automobile`).

Comment: If the method returned an object that had specific properties that were not part of the inherited AutoMobile class then yes you would need a cast. But from this example you would not.

Comment: This is just a basic example that i could think of.

Answers to some questions:
What is IAutomobile - I am wondering if this would be needed

Obviously it would have the properties that are the same as Automobile.

The problem i have is that because the items are retrieved from the database using an Id, i do not know what type of object the returning type would be. So an Id of 1 could be a car, but it could be a Coach, thus why i have a helper method that just returns a Object. Now the helperMethod returns Object, so i wondered how to cast to the "Base" object type

Comment: @user2736022 you already have a natural base class in `Automobile`. Have your helper class return that (it's already kinda obvious with the name of the helper method). Then there is absolutely no casting required. Think about it, it doesn't make sense to wrap your `Automobile` up as `object` to then cast it back does it?

Comment: @user2736022 your question is not about C# so please do not use it as tag (actually it's pretty language agnostic). Moreover IMO is primarily **opinion based** too.

Answer (score 3):

What is `IAutomobile` - you did not mention having an interface as well as an abstract base class.

Anyhow, in your example `EngineSize` is a member of the base class, so you should be able to assign it right on the `Automobile` variable without any explicit cast. However, if you want to set some specific field like `NumberOfDoors` then you have a number of options. Firstly, there is your option 1: just cast the result of `GetAutomobile` to a `Car`. But in all honesty, I would usually consider the need to know the derived type a flaw in the design and try to avoid it altogether - after all why would you try to work with an `Automobile` if you need specific properties depending on the type of automobile? In that case, it would be better to have a separate method `Helper.GetCar` and `Helper.GetCoach` which wrap the check and are guaranteed to return the correct object type, so you can also assign it directly to a `Car`.

Comment: +1. When you are downcasting like this you need to start wondering what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i do not know what type of object the returning type would be. So an Id of 1 could be a car, but it could be a Coach, thus why i have a helper method that just returns a Object

Comment: Ouch. If downcasting is a red flag already, returning an `Object` is even worse. Before you know it you'll be writing code like `if (returnValue is Car) { ... } else if (returnValue is Coach) { ... } else if ...`. Maybe you can expand your original post with a bit more information on how this is stored in the database and what your program will do, because I am starting to think you are trying to solve the wrong problem :-)

Comment: You dont need need to return just an object, return the base type.

Comment: Ric said "You dont need need to return just an object, return the base type." So no interface needed then. I guess i am trying to make things to complicated. Thanks

Comment: No, whether you use an interface or just a base class is a matter of style (and some factors which are probably irrelevant to you). I would say: choose one of the two, but not both, in this case.